# cat'ting files in the object store

Tags: git

Why does the following not work as expected?

```
$ find .git/objects -type f
.git/objects/5a/91f388f3648b98ae34a19ec42ba9acc7852ef4
$ git cat-file -t 91f388f3648b98ae34a19ec42ba9acc7852ef4
fatal: Not a valid object name 91f388f3648b98ae34a19ec42ba9acc7852ef4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the object ID is actually `5a91f388f3648b98ae34a19ec42ba9acc7852ef4`, the subdirectory `5a` is a part of the object ID.